# Сохранить изображение полученное через picasso в Bitmap переменной. Android

Tags: android, изображения, bitmap, picasso

С помощью библиотеки picasso получаю изображение по ссылке. Всё работает, если сразу отображать в imageView. Но когда я пытаюсь сохранить в bitmap переменной или в коллекции List я получаю ошибку. Размер коллекции равен 0, данные просто не сохраняются в переменной. Скажите, пожалуйста как это можно реализовать или другие библиотеки, которые мне могут в этом помочь.

```
List<Bitmap> bm;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

bm = new ArrayList<>();

bm = listBitmap;

ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bm.get(1)); // 1 or other index (not work)
}

public List<Bitmap> listBitmap(){
List<Bitmap> list = new ArrayList<>(); 

Picasso.with(this).load(url)
                .into(new Target() {
                    @Override
                    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, 
Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {

                       // Not work!!!
                       list.add(bitmap);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) 
{

                    }
                });

  return list;
}
```

Comment: во-первых - картинка грузится  асинхронно, т.е. надо дождаться конца загрузки и потом сетить во вьюху, во вторых индекс начинается с 0

Comment: При индексе 0 - результат такой же. Когда сразу устанавлюю картинку для view, то всё работает. Мне нужно чтобы картинка пошла в коллекцию, и от туда я её вытяну.

Comment: Картинки грузятся в другом потоке, а Ваш метод `listBitmap()` немедленно возвращает пустой список, который потом, по мере загрузки, заполняется. Но Вы обращаетесь к списку сразу же, когда он ещё пустой.

Comment: Можете подсказать, как я определить, что картинки были загружены в коллекцию и её уже можно получить?

Comment: Вы бы подробнее описали задачу - мне кажется `Picasso` для таких целей не очень-то подходит. И много картинок в памяти могут не уместиться (`OutOfMemoryError` схлопотать очень легко).

Comment: Есть `RecyclerView`, который имеет `Textview` и `ImageView`. В БД храняться ссылки на разные сайты. Нужно заполнить список `RecyclerView` этими ссылками и одной картинкой на каждую ссылку. Ссылку на именно картинку получаю с помощью `Jsoup`, путем парсинга ссылки из БД (та, что в `TextView`). Все эти процессы делаю в `AsyncTask`.

Answer (score 0):

Picasso кэширует изображения, поэтому хранить картинки в памяти не стоит. Стоит только разобраться с кэшированием.

Если вернуться к изначальному вопросу: попробуйте использовать picasso.Callback

```
Callback imageLoadedCallback = new Callback() {
@Override
public void onSuccess() {
    //здесь ваш код
}

@Override
public void onError() {
}
};
Picasso.with(this).load(url).into(.into(imageView, imageLoadedCallback);
```